# Migrate SQL 2008 database to Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, log-shipping, azure-sql

I am migrating a SQL server 2008 R2 production database to Azure SQL database service in the cloud.

Is it possible to mirror/replicate the Azure database from the 2008 R2 database? So I can just switch over to just using the new one. Instead of take it offline, create a bacpac file,  upload it to azure storage,  and restore from that one.

I want to do this to reduce downtime during the migration.

Azure doesn't support the traditional log-shipping, and [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt589530.aspx) require that you are moving from a 2012 database or newer.

Edit: Made the question much clearer.

Comment: Forgot my question.. I haven't found a good answer to this one yet. We went with the manual approach: Took it offline, created a bacpac file, uploaded it to azure storage, and restored from that one.

Comment: Note worthy. 
SQL Replication to Azure is now generally available. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-database-is-now-generally-available/

Answer (score 5):

Since you need to migrate SQL 2008 to a new host, I would suggest you follow [the blog post](http://bidn.com/blogs/MMilligan/bidn-blog/3207/how-to-migrate-an-instance-of-sql-server-2008-to-a-new-server) instructions. That works for me.

Comment: Since this have nothing to do with Azure database service. This won't help me at all. I have updated the question a bit to make it more clear of what I am looking for.